# Subversion gem to track commit history in Ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svn, rubygems

Currently I'm doing research for a custom build deployment application on a unix system. I've also looked at Capistrano so don't worry ;). I'm looking for a gem that can give me the (subversion) commit stream of several projects. I'd like to run some tests with it to determine if it's possible/necessary to build a custom made deployment application.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK git is more preferred in the Ruby land

Comment: i know but we use subversion so i'm bound to that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following URL :

http://www.oneofthewolves.com/2007/03/06/ruby-subversion-bindings-finally-some-documentation/